# How to configure Hibernate in JBoss

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am creating an application to be run on JBoss using hibernate. When I run the app I get the following error:

```
    21:15:55,848 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/researchprojects
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]

21:15:55,911 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000299: Could not complete schema update: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/researchprojects
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
```

I have included the mysql driver in the WEB-INF/lib folder and I have also added it in the build path. I havent modified the standalone.xml file since I include all the required information about connecting to the db in the persistence.xml file.

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="test"  >
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>    
    <!-- <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>  -->        
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>    
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>   
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/researchprojects"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="351984"/>            
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Anybody could gimme a hint how to solve this issue? I have looked all the related posts before post here , but nothing helped me.Thnx

Answer (score 3):

Configure hibernate in jboss:

I used the following configuration for jboss 7.1.1 final

1)
create the folder mysql in jboss path:JBOSS_HOME/modules/com and again create one more folder main in side the mysql
So path will be like this JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main,
inside the main foler add the the module.xml and mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
your module.xml should like this....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

2)

Add module name  in module.xml to JBOSS_HOME/module/org/hibernate/main/module.xml
So the module.xml for hibernate should like:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
    <module name="com.mysql"/> 
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="4" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" services="import" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

3)
Create the data-source in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/data-source-name" pool-name="data-source-name" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data-base-name</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

4)
Add the java:jboss/datasources/data-source-name in persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="abc" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/eSociety</jta-data-source>
<!-- map your classes. -->
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
</properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It is enough for hibernate configuration with jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the jpa property for the driver class.  You just need to add the entry below to your properties entry.

```
<properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</properties>
```