# JPA+mysql No suitable driver found when deployed to JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jpa, jboss

I know this has been asked so many times but still I couldn't find a solution to it. I am using JPA + Hibernate provider + MySQL in my spring mvc project. When I deploy it to Tomcat, it executes with no problem. Then when I move it to JBoss 7.1.1. it throws me No suitable Driver found exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

So I narrow this down to JBoss.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="personDB">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.springapp.modlels.OfficeEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="9ijn)OKM"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is my calling code

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("personDB");
        EntityManager mgr = emf.createEntityManager();
        mgr.getTransaction().begin();
        OfficeEntity officeEntity = new OfficeEntity();
        officeEntity.setOfficeName("test");
        mgr.persist(officeEntity);
        mgr.getTransaction().commit();
```

It looks like the JBoss cannot find the suitable driver when getTransaction() get called. And my driver is

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
```

UPDATED:David Levesque suggested me to install the JDBC driver to JBoss.
This is what i did in \modules\com\mysql\main, I copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar here and created the module.xml,

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I also modified the \standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/mysqldb" pool-name="my_mysl" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>9ijn)OKM</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

And I also tested the datasource in JBoss console and it connects succesfully.
But I am sorry, by adding this, it still shows me the same exception.

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: You also need to point your persistence.xml to use the datasource you've specified in standalone.xml .

Comment: Is this datasource necessary if I have all the connection info in the persistence.xml?

Comment: Yes, datasourse is necessary because you using JBoss. It will take the connection from datasourse when you deploy your project not from persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hibernate configuration is fine for jboss, but i think you missed the one part to configure hibernate with jboss.

1) So please add the dependencies `<module name="com.mysql"/>` in the `module.xml` in the

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\hibernate\main\module.xml
```

2) Create the correct data source in your standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mysqldb" pool-name="my_mysl" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>9ijn)OKM</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

3)  Remove the following properties from persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="9ijn)OKM"/>
```

Except these your configuration is right but please correct your peaces of code with above changes. Your error will resolve...

For the reference, you can follow this link [Configure hibernate in jboss 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060051/how-to-configure-hibernate-in-jboss/21159460#21159460)

Thank you...