# MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss7.x

I have problem with my project using Jboss 7.0 
I can't build that.

This is my problem

```
19:00:38,809 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."brangista.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."brangista.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "brangista.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class com.brangista.base.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:122)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:40)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEApplicationDescription.getClassConfiguration(EEApplicationDescription.java:183)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription.createConfiguration(ComponentDescription.java:153)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.brangista.base.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter from [Module "deployment.brangista.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_35]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:139)
... 11 more

19:00:39,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "brangista.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"brangista.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"brangista.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"brangista.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista ]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista ]"]}
19:00:39,240 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Stopped deployment brangista.war in 223ms
19:00:39,242 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"brangista.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"brangista.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"brangista.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista ]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.brangista.brangista ]"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the class `com.brangista.base.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` actually exist in the `war` or the classpath.  It seems to be referenced in the `web.xml` file but cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error,

1. check your database source setup with Jboss is well define(I mean in JBOSS_Home/modules/com/mysql/main/module.xml and JBOSS_Home/modules/org/your source setup )
2. define your database in standalone.xml
3. Set up persistent.xml
4. clean server and start server.

for guidelines: [How to configure Hibernate in JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060051/how-to-configure-hibernate-in-jboss)

If still a same problem then check your project structure.